# How to open selected (checked) nodes on jstree load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using jsTree to display my database hierarchy categories like interactive tree. Initial load is done with JSON, and by default some categories are checked. jsTree knows which categories are selected because it shows them as checked (I am using checkbox plugin), but I want to be able to open that checked nodes (and all their parents) on tree load.

I need that because, when user open a page with tree he is not aware that there might be some categories selected without expanding whole tree, and I would like to expand only those nodes that are checked.

This is my code so far:

```
var tree = $('.tree').bind('loaded.jstree', function (e, data) {

              // I assume that logic that expand checked nodes must be placed here, after tree is loaded

    })
    .jstree({
        // Configure JSON data plugin
        'json_data': {
            'data': [<this is initial json data>]
        },

        'checkbox': {
            'override_ui': true,
            'two_state': true,
            'real_checkboxes': true
        },

        // Specify which plugins to load
        'plugins': ['themes', 'json_data', 'ui', 'checkbox']
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: did u find any solution to this? i am looking for same solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the state plugin,
You will have to set the state at the checked nodes to open.

In the plugin array add "state".
In the json of the tree, after the data of each node, add an object like so:
state: {
    opened : true
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the **state** plugin is required.  It saves the state of the tree and reopens the tree to that state when it is next encountered.

Importantly though, @alostr is correct that if you set the data of your node to **state: { opened : true }** it will open that node after it is displayed.